# To what extent were mathematicians in previous centuries aware of the lack of rigour in their methods?

Tags: soft-question, math-history

By modern standards, much of pre-modern mathematics isn't rigorous. Famous examples include [Euler's solution to the Basel problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem#Euler.27s_approach) or literally *anything* involving sets before Cantor and Russel came along, when a "set" was simply a handwaving notion of "all things that have some property", later found to be [quite problematic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox).

To what extent were the mathematicians of the past aware of these shortcomings? Did they even feel mathematics needed to be a rigorous subject, or was there an idea that anything goes as long as it works?

I feel this question is not just of historical interest. Modern mathematics is usually judged (by modern mathematics) to be rigorous, but we have no reason to believe we are able to assess our methods correctly unless our predecessors were capable of assessing theirs.

Comment: It's been more than a month with no replies. Instead of migrating the question, you may want to ask it in HSM.

Comment: Your underlying question of assessing our methods can be answered by looking at formal systems which are perfectly precise and govern what strings of symbols from a finite alphabet have meaning (called well-formed) and which can be derived from which (rules). The reason previous mathematicians did not assess their mathematical rigour very well is probably because they had poor grasp of algorithms or did not consider proofs as strings that follow a strict syntax, and so judgement of correctness depends on intuition rather than mechanical checking. What is unverifiable is validity of axioms.

Comment: @user21820: In theory, that is correct. In practice, the vast majority of proofs published today are still not formal but written in prose, and some key theorems from the past are expected to take decades to formalize (classification of finite simple groups for example). Nevertheless, modern proofs are usually called *rigorous* even if they are largely presented in standard human language, which lacks the formal qualities required to be "certain" of their correctness.

Comment: @pew: Very true, but there is still a difference. In the past mathematicians were not even aware of the possibility of reducing all deductions to finite strings and string manipulations, because they did not think carefully enough about the (philosophical) issues of what axioms to accept. Now at least they are aware of the possibility of an axiomatic system to ground their work. So even though they do not write in formal proofs, they can usually tell you what axiom or rule they use at any point in their proof should you question them. What remains a problem is careless mistakes.

Comment: In fact, until very recently mathematicians really did not have a clear idea of algorithms. I suppose one could say that it was largely because of the construction of programmable computers that that viewpoint was largely clarified. Without a clear understanding of algorithms, it is quite difficult to grasp the possibility of a formal system in the first place.

Comment: I would also say that, since mathematics has gone a long way since the pre-modern era, today it is much harder just to "have an intuition", or at least, to have an intuition which everyone shares. Math has become quite too hard for that. So rigor is becoming more important to convince the others of your ideas.

Answer (score 4):

Lagrange launched a contest at the end of the 18th century whose goal was to clarify the notions of infinity and infinitesimal. There was no clear winner, but Lazare Carnot submitted an entry which eventually became a popular book. This is only one episodes illustrating the fact that rigor has indeed been a concern historically.

A century earlier, there was a debate at the French academy focusing on similar issues, opposing Rolle and Varignon.

In the 19th century, Cauchy lists rigor as one of the objectives of his approach to analysis.

So to answer your question, mathematicians in previous centuries were aware of lack of rigor, but in most cases attributed it to their predecessors only. This seems to be the case today, as well.

Answer (score -2):

It is a little known fact that much of Bernhardt Riemann's work had remained un-rigorous until Hilbert's arrival on the mathematical scene some fifty years after Riemann's death.  Riemann was aware of his shortcomings, but many before him were not.  Did you know that complex numbers were not properly accepted until the nineteenth century?  The historian D.T. Whiteside considered Newton's first proposition in the Principia to be problemmatic.  According to Michael Atiyah, it took hundreds of years after Newton's death for calculus to be made properly rigorous.  It is worth pointing out that in Newton's day, Euclidean geometry was considered to be more rigorous than the new-fangled algebraic approach introduced by Descartes (according to historian of mathematics S. Hollingdale).  Also, Euler was ignorant of the fact that he had made some completely incorrect deductions concerning alternating series.  Of course, we know from the correspondence of G.H. Hardy that the great Ramanujan did not possess properly rigorous proofs for several of his 4000+ theorems.  In the nineteenth century there was at least one mathematician who had erroneously believed during his lifetime he had correctly proved a special case of Fermat's last theorem.  According to Felix Klein, even the great Gauss did not appear to be to concerned about being rigorous when he was involved with more practically inclined investigations.  But Gauss was well aware of this.

Answer (score -2):

First of all it is not really historically meaningful to phrase the question "To what extent.."  and "aware of lack of rigour". To really know the answer we would surely need a time machine, which we do not have (at least I don't.) Additionally, the question also deals with awareness which is a delicate and [debatable](https://www.google.co.il/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=debates%20about%20awareness%20psychology&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=yQoUVoLaLqeH8Qe2gpXACA) subject even in its own field, namely psychology. So let's assume you are aware of your own thoughts and feeling and your own knowledge. But are you aware of thoughts and of feelings of someone else? How can you be sure you are? And even more, How can you be aware of the things you do not know?

History and the Scientific process should be understood in the context they occurred. The mathematicians of previous times where trying to lay their grasp of the world mathematically with the syntactical tools they had or could invent. Understandably, there are a lot of tools and concepts that where developed after their time which they could not use in their research.

So, removing the psychological notion which is only can be answered with conjectures and guessworks. It is logical to say that their proofs and mathematical language and deduction was just rigour enough to be accepted by their contemporaries, and than re-examined and change like in other [scientific areas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Structure_of_Scientific_Revolutions) Like claimed by [Popper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Popper) and then [Kuhn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Kuhn).

Wikipedia has what seems to be a really good, yet short, description of the term [rigour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigour#Mathematics) in the context of mathematics and its historical context. The key thing you can take from this answer is that historical events and peoples thoughts (and feelings) are heavily influenced by their time and contextual frame. I hope this answer explain and give you some of the necessary information and a viable direction to understand these concepts in clear way.

Comment: This is a non-answer.

Comment: What could you not understand? I thought it explained the issue pretty clearly

Comment: You simply haven't answered the question.

Comment: I answered it. Maybe it's hard to understand for someone who only does math. But the question was meta question so the answer has to be like that too.

Comment: The short answer is that they were not aware because they could not possibly be aware to anything developed after their time.

Comment: Some of them were very much aware. Bishop Berkeley's [The Analyst](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Analyst) is a sophisticated critique of the flimsy foundations of Newton's calculus, written in 1734.

Comment: I believe that Newton died in 1726 therefore, he could not possibly be aware of the Bishops works at 1734. But maybe that's counterintuitive. Now more seriously that is hefty 50 years after the discovery of fluctuations  by Newton. And it is only further support my claim about scientific method.  Which apparently also happen in Mathematics after all.

Comment: 1734 certainly counts as "previous centuries". Also, "fluxions".

Comment: Yes Newton was aware his fluxions was not perfect that's why he did not publish it until he was pressed by Leibniz advancements. That whole controversy happened in 1666-1700 not in 1734.  But they are all surly aware that they publish as far as they can know and to as much rigour as they can.

Comment: You are contradicting yourself! Comment #5: "The short answer is that they were not aware...". Comment #9: "Yes Newton was aware..." You see why I downvoted your answer now?

Comment: It is not a contradiction because I use the word "aware" in different context.The truth is that scientist are aware to their limitations as human beings and in their works sometimes. But!!! they cannot be aware of the future developments. Some arguments in science are naturally stronger than others and hold for more time. But in that sense Mathematics is also a form of science so the flaws in rigour get corrected with time and new syntactically tools are achieved.  So he was aware that is not perfect but he did not know what was not perfect because he couldn't and in order to do that he might

Comment: have had to live half a century later
P.S. I think you got an answer.

Comment: Given the overwhelming tendency of modern mathematicians to compare their methods to those of ancient Greece explicitly with regard to their rigor, it seems quite absurd to treat "rigor" as some inherently 19th- or 20th-century concept. Cavalieri's writing spends half its time justifying his techniques, while his successors often explicitly scorned others' requests for rigor. This has always been an issue!

Comment: I will expect it to ever become more "rigour". Precisly because the definition of rigour is time and culture related. Also some fields of math are naturaly more logical than others. Math of motion for example is also confind to the rules of motion. I mean: who defines what is currently counts as rigour - clearly the people who live now. But still there are some synthactical progresses.